# Is there any theory about extra-Universal place?

Tags: multiverse

I mean you can probably imagine cells and extracellular space between them. In biology some things can go through the cell membrane in and out.

What if universe/s are "similar" and some form of "energy" can leave the Universe and go to extra-universal place? And if it has certain amount new baby Universe is born?

Are there some theories that operates with something I have speak above?

Comment: What do you mean under "universe"? As it currently stands, it seems to me, you mean the continuation of the usual 3D space under this term. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, I don't mean the 10th dimension projection. just the classical "bubbles" popping out and crushing if they are too big ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, some authors have considered the possibility of our observable universe being embedded in a higher-dimensional one, see [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9906064) for an example.